# Convert animation on curve modifier for Unity

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, unity, path

[image]

As you can see in the gif above, I have a very simple animation along a path. Basically, the snake has an unapplied curve modifier and simply moving it on the Y axis creates this animation. However, if I simply apply the curve modifier, the snake will be stop deforming and move on the Y axis instead of moving ALONG the path and deforming. Since I cannot export the path and animate the snake on that path in Unity, what would be the best way to export that animation to the game engine?